# R: Calculate and display percentages using dplyr and geom_text

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, geom-text

```
df <- data.frame(Language = factor(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), levels = 1:2, labels = c("GER", "ENG")),
                 Agegrp =   factor(c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 4, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 4), levels = c( 1, 2, 3, 4), labels = c("10-19", "20-29", "30-39", "40+")) 
                 ) 
  

df %>% ggplot(aes(x = Agegrp, fill = Language)) + 
  geom_bar(position = 'dodge') +
  labs(title = "Age-structure between German and English",
       y = "Number of persons")
```

Using the above sample data I can create the following plot. But

- how can I calculate the percentages of each agegroup *within* each language (using dplyr) and
- how can I do the same plot with percentages (y-axis should be percentages)?

[image]

In this example the percentages are very easy to see as both languages have the same number of cases (10) but this does not necessarily have to be the case with real data. Thank you for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To calculate percentage of each `Agegrp` within a `Language` you can try -

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df %>%
  count(Agegrp, Language) %>%
  group_by(Language) %>%
  mutate(n = prop.table(n)) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Agegrp, y = n, fill = Language)) + 
  geom_col(position = 'dodge') +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) + 
  labs(title = "Age-structure between German and English",
       y = "Percentage of persons")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add percentages on the bars you could use this code. The logic of calculating the percentage is the same as with Ronak (credits to Ronak)

```
df %>% 
  count(Language, Agegrp) %>% 
  group_by(Language) %>% 
  mutate(percent = prop.table(n)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Agegrp, y = percent, fill = Language, label = scales::percent(percent))) + 
  geom_col(position = 'dodge') +
  geom_text(position = position_dodge(width = .9),    # move to center of bars
            vjust = -0.5,    # nudge above top of bar
            size = 3) + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
  labs(title = "Age-structure between German and English",
       y = "Number of persons")
```

[image]